# OWL universal quantification

Tags: owl

I am half way reading the [OWL2 primer](http://www.w3.org/2007/OWL/wiki/Primer) and is having problem understanding the [universal quantification](http://www.w3.org/2007/OWL/wiki/Primer#Property_Restrictions)

The example given is

```
EquivalentClasses(
    :HappyPerson 
    ObjectAllValuesFrom( :hasChild :HappyPerson )
)
```

It says somebody is a happy person exactly if all their children are happy persons. But what if John Doe has no children can he be an instance of HappyPerson? What about his parent?

I also find this part very confusing, it says:

Hence, by our above statement, every childless person would be qualified as happy.

but wouldn't it violate the ObjectAllValuesFrom() constructor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the [primer](http://www.w3.org/2007/OWL/wiki/Primer#Property_Restrictions) actually does quite a good job at explaining this, particularly the following:

> Natural
>   language indicators for the usage of
>   universal quantification are words
>   like “only,” “exclusively,” or
>   “nothing but.”

To simplify this a bit further, consider the expression you've given:

`HappyPerson ≡ ∀ hasChild . HappyPerson`

This says that a `HappyPerson` is someone who **only** has children who are also `HappyPerson` (are also happy). Logically, this actually says nothing about the existence of instances of happy children. It simply serves as a universal constraint on any children that *may* exist (note that this includes any instances of `HappyPerson` that don't have any children).

Compare this to the [existential quantifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_quantification), exists (∃):

`HappyPerson ≡ ∃ hasChild . HappyPerson`

This says that a `HappyPerson` is someone who has **at least one** child that is also a `HappyPerson`. In constrast to (∀), this expression actually implies the existence of a happy child for every instance of a `HappyPerson`.

The answer, albeit initially unintuitive, lies in the interpretation/semantics of the `ObjectAllValuesFrom` OWL construct in first-order logic (actually, Description Logic). Fundamentally, the `ObjectAllValuesFrom` construct relates to the [logical universal quantifier (∀)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantification), and the `ObjectSomeValuesFrom` construct relates to the [logical existential quantifier (∃)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_quantification).

Answer (score -1):

I am facing the same kind of issue while reading the "OWL 2 Web Ontology Language Primer (Second Edition - 2012)" and I am not convinced that the answer by Sharky clarifies the issue.

At page 15, when introducing the universal quantifier ∀, the book states:
 "Another property restriction, called universal quantification is used to describe a class of individuals for which all related individuals must be instances of a given class. We can use the following statement to indicate that somebody is a happy person exactly if all their children are happy persons."
 [I omit the OWL statements in the different sintaxes, they can be found in the book.]
 I think that a more formal and may be less ambiguos representation of what the author states is

(1) HappyPerson = {x | ∀y (x HasChild y → y ∈ HappyPerson)}

I hope every reader understands this notation, because I find the notation used in the answer less clear (or may be I am just not accustomed to it).

The book proceeds:
 "... There is one particular misconception concerning the universal role restriction. As an example, consider the above happiness axiom. The intuitive reading suggests that in order to be happy, a person must have at least one happy child [my note: actually the definition states that every children should be happy, not just at least one, in order for his/her parents to be happy. This appears to be a lapsus of the author]. Yet, this is not the case: any individual that is not a “starting point” of the property hasChild is a class member of any class defined by universal quantification over hasChild. Hence, by our above statement, every childless person would be qualified as happy . ..."
 That is, the author states that (assume '~' for logical NOT), given

(2) ChildessPerson = { x | ~∃y( x HasChild y)}

then (1) and the meaning of ∀ imply

(3)  ChildessPerson ⊂ HappyPerson

This does not seem true to me.
 If it were true then every child, as far as s/he is a childless person, is happy and so only some parents can be unhappy persons.

Consider this model:

> Persons = {a,b,c}, HasChild = {(a,b)}, HappyPerson={a,b}

and c is unhappy (independently from the close world or open world assumption). It is a possible model, which falsifies the thesis of the author.